# Struts2 Validations xml in different directory?

Tags: xml, validation, struts2, action

Is it possible to have the `"actionclasses"-validation.xml` files in a different directory than the actions classes?

My idea is organizing them in this format:

**ActionsPackage:**

```
action1.java
action2.java

...
```

**ValidationsPackage:**

```
action1-validation.xml
action2-validation.xml

...
```

Answer (score 0):

**Nutshell:** It makes zero difference where they are on the filesystem as long as they're in the correct place during *deployment*.

**Longer Answer:**
It sounds like you don't know how to use your build environment or IDE.

For example, using Maven, pretty much the standard these days<sup>1</sup>, the validation XML files would live in `src/main/resources` in the same directory/package hierarchy as the actions.

In an IDE, if you're not using Maven, you can create new source directories besides, say, `src`, and put the configuration files there.

Answer (score 0):

The `ActionClass-validation.xml` should be in the same Java package (folder) where the `ActionClass` is.

But using a [`DefaultActionValidatorManager`](http://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/validator/DefaultActionValidatorManager.html) is possible to configure `ActionClass-validation.xml` and `ActionInterface-validation.xml` that could be in different packages.

> This is the entry point into XWork's rule-based validation framework.
>
> Validation rules are specified in XML configuration files named
>   `className-contextName-validation.xml` where className is the name of
>   the class the configuration is for and `-contextName` is optional
>   (`contextName` is an arbitrary key that is used to look up additional
>   validation rules for a specific context).